# SQL to get next monday in Presto

Tags: sql, datetime, presto, amazon-athena, date-arithmetic

I need to get the date for next Monday irrespective of which day the sql is executed.

I think the logic `7 - day_of_week(current_date)%7 + 1` would work, but then how to get the date.

```
select current_date;

    _col0
1   2019-11-16


select (7 - day_of_week(current_date)%7+1)


    _col0
1   2
```

Or is there any other better way to do the same.

I will appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
date_add(day, 8 - extract(day_of_week from current_date), current_date)
```

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help. Just a small change - ```select date_add('day', 8 - extract(day_of_week from current_date), current_date) ```

Comment: @Anand: yes checking the docs I can see that I inverted the value and the timestamp. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`date_trunc`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#truncation-function) to get the Monday of the current week and add 7 days to it:

```
presto> select date_trunc('week', current_date) + interval '7' day;

   _col0
------------
 2019-11-18
(1 row)
```